# how to after the Animate() scrollTop then change a css background-color

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#goto').click(function(){ 
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#content').offset().top-100},800);
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800); 
  });
});
</script>
```

#goto is go

#content is .......

I want the users if click #goto will scroll to #content

this function is ok!

but I want the same time will change the background-color of ul#content

how can I do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery can't animate colors by default, you either need to use the [offical jquery color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) or you can do it by css property without animation.

CSS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9k84X/

jQuery Color Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9k84X/2/

CSS Example:

```
$(function(){
  $('#goto').click(function(){    
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#content').offset().top-100},800);
    $('#content').css({'background-color': "#a7bf51"});
  });
});
```

jQuery Color Example:

```
$(function(){
  $('#goto').click(function(){ 
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop:$('#content').offset().top-100
      }, 800);
      $("#content").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"
      }, 800);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! I using the css example thanks again

Comment: welcome, if you think that this answer matches your needs, please review the answer with marking the tick sign next to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback.

More information in http://api.jquery.com/animate/

this should work, but check it, maybe you may need change $(this) value to a specific DOM.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#goto').click(function(){ 
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#content').offset().top-100},800,function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800); 
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks and I will have a try